# Android: How can I detect manufacturer and change program behavior

Tags: android

I have an app that I have written that works fine on the Samsung Galaxy S series (I have a captivate).  However, the app apparently doesn't work on the Droid's as Motorola has laid out the file structure differently.

I'm looking for a way to detect the manufacturer so that I can switch out program behavior.

Does anyone know an easy way to do this?

Comment: I assume this is for a rooted phone? If not, why do you need specific directory structures?

Answer (score 2):

[`android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MANUFACTURER) is probably what you want.

Bear in mind that the file structure is likely to vary on other devices as well, as that's not part of the public SDK.

Answer (score 0):

This what you need in addition to manufacturer: 
 **android.os.Build.MODEL**;